# Django add a model field based on another field

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django and know there has to be an easy way to do this that makes sense: I have a form where I would like the user to enter the URL for a YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX). I would like to take input and convert it to the format to embed a YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXXXX).

My models.py field uses a URL field. I don't have a forms.py file (I'm willing to add one if needed) and instead, I'm calling the models.py fields individually on my HTML page.

### I'm happy to take any advice on if you would add a forms.py file. I imagine the cleanest way to move from one URL format to the other on user entry is to slice the original user input and concatenate but I don't know where or with what format in Django.

edit with code:
I used a suggestion and added a line to my views.py file but it I think I might be referencing it wrong as I can't get it to populate in my HTML file. any thoughts are appreciated

models.py

```
class HomeDesc(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(default = 00000)
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    full_bathrooms = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    half_bathrooms = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    video = models.URLField(max_length=400, default = 'xxx')
```

views.py

```
def SingleHome(request, pk):
    hl = HomeDesc.objects.get(pk=pk)
    video_embed = hl.video.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/")
    ctx = {'home': hl, 'video': video_embed}
    return render(request, template_name = 'homedb/single_home.html', context=ctx)
```

A portion of the html file:

```
% if home %}
            <h1>{{ home.street }}</h1>
            <ul>

            <li><iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ video.video_embed }}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li>City: {{ home.city }}</li>
```

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unsure as to where but as far as the how, I think the simplest way to do it would be something as follows

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX"
url = url.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/")
```

Regarding the where, I am assuming you would do this in the controller in whichever method you need this in. Hope this could be of some use to you.